# Error during compile Gupta application version 7.0

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, centura

I'm trying to compile a gupta application version 7.0, after that it return me the following error:
"Cannot load or find external library (or one of its componentes). Check to ensure the path and filename are correct and that all required libraries are available."
The error is about a DLL whose name is biptoAfcsAdapter.dll but this DLL is inside the execution path of the application.

How can i fix it?

Comment: I had to set my IDE's global search path to be able to find our custom .apl libs.

Answer (score 0):

This is definatley a third party dll, not a Gupta one, so maybe the dll needs registering. Maybe the dll is in a restricted folder that TD cant get to . Also, TD7 is UNICODE, so all the parameters into the external functions of the dll need to be the appropriate UNICODE compatible varient , esp. strings e.g.

[image]

Check your 'Tools' --> 'Preferences; --> 'Directories', and put a leading semi-colon in 'Global Path' and tick the Global path option. e.g.

[image]

p.s. You don't specify if you are running 32bit or 64bit TeamDeveloper v7.
If 64bit, and the dll is 32bit, or vica versa, you need a new dll.